# Elasticsearch adding new fields showing Error in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using the  Elasticsearch JSON  Mapping as

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "test": {
            "_routing": {
                "path": "harvestdate", 
                "required": true
            }, 
            "_source": {
                "enabled": false
            }, 
            "properties": {
                "infoid": {
                    "precision_step": "0", 
                    "store": "yes", 
                    "type": "long"
                }, 
                "productid": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed", 
                    "omit_norms": "true", 
                    "omit_term_freq_and_positions": "true", 
                    "store": "yes", 
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "saleid": {
                    "precision_step": "0", 
                    "store": "yes", 
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. I am using the Index as index1
2. I have to add a new field in the JSON  and it looks like

   `{
       "mappings": {
           "test": {
               "_routing": {
                   "path": "harvestdate",
                   "required": true
               },
               "_source": {
                   "enabled": false
               },
               "properties": {
                   "deal": {
                       "index": "not_analyzed",
                       "omit_norms": "true",
                       "omit_term_freq_and_positions": "true",
                       "store": "no",
                       "type": "string"
                   },
                   "infoid": {
                       "precision_step": "0",
                       "store": "yes",
                       "type": "long"
                   },
                   "productid": {
                       "index": "not_analyzed",
                       "omit_norms": "true",
                       "omit_term_freq_and_positions": "true",
                       "store": "yes",
                       "type": "string"
                   },
                   "saleid": {
                       "precision_step": "0",
                       "store": "yes",
                       "type": "long"
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }`

I am trying to update this mapping using Elasticsearch with the Index(index1) by using the command

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/index1/test/_mapping' -d  '{
    "mappings": {
        "test": {
            "_routing": {
                "path": "harvestdate", 
                "required": true
            }, 
            "_source": {
                "enabled": false
            }, 
            "properties": {
                "deal": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed", 
                    "omit_norms": "true", 
                    "omit_term_freq_and_positions": "true", 
                    "store": "no", 
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "infoid": {
                    "precision_step": "0", 
                    "store": "yes", 
                    "type": "long"
                }, 
                "productid": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed", 
                    "omit_norms": "true", 
                    "omit_term_freq_and_positions": "true", 
                    "store": "yes", 
                    "type": "string"
                }, 
                "saleid": {
                    "precision_step": "0", 
                    "store": "yes", 
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

While checking the mapping the mapping it is not Set with the Updated 
Mapping in the Index(index1). What is the error in this curl or mapping?

Thanks in Advance!

Cheers!

Comment: I don't understand why the second block does not want to indent properly…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove the

```
"mappings": {
```

thing. From what I read (don't remember where, but on the elastic search mailing list, the "mappings" comes from the `GET`, but should not be here when `PUTing`, and IIRC, they want to do something in next versions about it).

Comment: I tried by removing the "mappings": { .... }  I am getting the following error...

Comment: I tried by removing the "mappings": { .... }  I am getting the following error... ></html>curl: (6) Could not resolve host: true,omit_term_freq_and_positions; No data record of requested type
l><head><title>Apache Tomcat/5.5.26 - Error report.....h1>HTTP Status 403 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report...body></html>curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 5
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket at pos 1

Comment: @George it seems it cannot connect to Elastic Search. Something is wrong somewhere else ;-)

Comment: Hi, I am getting the error  message as    C:\Users\Admin>    .p4qt"productid" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "no", "index" : "not_analyzed","omit_norms" : "true", "omit_term_freq
_and_positions" : "true"}
'.p4qt"productid"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Admin>                }
'}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: While running the curl in the command prompt it is showing the above error  as.....  curl: (1) Protocol 'http not supported or disabled in libcurl
C:\Users\Admin>    "test" : {
'"test"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.